# Handling scope for single and double quote strings in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am working with ANTLR4 and in the process of writing grammar to handle single and double quoted strings. I am trying to use Lexer modes to scope the strings but that is not working out for me, my grammar is listed below. Is this the right way or how can I properly parse these as tokens instead of parser rules with context. Any insight?

An example:

```
'single quote that contain "a double quote 'that has another single quote'"'
```

Lexer Grammar

```
lexer grammar StringLexer;

fragment SQUOTE: '\'';

fragment QUOTE:  '"';

SQSTR_START: SQUOTE     -> pushMode(SQSTR_MODE);

DQSTR_START: QUOTE      -> pushMode(DQSTR_MODE);

CONTENTS: ~["\']+;

mode SQSTR_MODE;

SQSTR_END: (CONTENTS | DQSTR_START)+ SQUOTE -> popMode;

mode DQSTR_MODE;

DQSTR_END:(CONTENTS | SQSTR_START)+ QUOTE -> popMode;
```

Parser

```
parser grammar StringParser;
options { tokenVocab=StringLexer; }

start:
    dqstr | sqstr
;

dqstr:
 DQSTR_START DQSTR_END
 ;  

sqstr:
 SQSTR_START SQSTR_END
;
```

**ADDENDUM**
Thanks @Lucas Trzesniewski for an answer.

This is part of grammar I am writing to parse shell-like language, I could have multiple lines of script where they would have `SQSTR` and `DQSTR`. With the lexer rules provided in the answer it would lump multiple lines of script together.

Happy case example (That get parsed correctly using the answer):

```
cmd 'single quote string'
cmd2 "double quote"
cmd3 'another single quote'
```

This get recognized as three commands and three strings (single and double)

Unparsed example: On the other hand - note the quote in the single quote strings:

```
cmd 'single "quote string'
cmd2 "double quote"
cmd3 'another "single quote'
```

In this case it would incorrectly detect all of them as a single string token of type SQSTR.

Any ideas how to address this problem?

Comment: My answer is still valid, even after your edit. Try it out. Embeded double quotes in a single-quote string and a single quote in a double quoted string are matched like any other char in that string. Nothing special to do here.

Comment: @MikeLischke Hi Mike, yes it would handle this case but there are other scenarios for containment `" double containing 'single containing "double that contains 'single'"'"` that would fail with this grammar.

Answer (score 3):

Way too complicated, what you have in mind. Where did you see such a solution before? (Almost) all grammars in the grammar repository on github which have such rules use a simple and nicely working approach, where you have an introducer, content and terminator, all in one rule, e.g.:

```
SQSTRING: '\'' .*? '\'';
DQSTRING: '"' .*? '"';
```

Similarly for all other elements with that kind of structure (single quoted string, back tick quoted string, multiline comment etc.).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse your example string as a single token, you don't necessarily have to use lexer modes, you can use mutually-recursive lexer rules instead:

```
SQSTR : '\'' (~['"] | DQSTR)* '\'';
DQSTR : '"'  (~['"] | SQSTR)* '"';
```

Then, in the parser use something like:

```
str : SQSTR | DQSTR;
```

Comment: This would handle single instances of strings properly, but if I have multiple instances in the same snippet I am attempting to parse it would include all of the strings in a single token. If I add "*?" to have it become not greedy, it would not handle cases where strings contain other strings properly. Any ideas?

Comment: @JafarKofahi I don't understand what you're talking about, you may want to ask a new question, along with an example.

Comment: @ Lucas Trzesniewski I updated my question to explain the issue this grammar has. I attempted to address it in various forms but couldnt, any ideas?

Comment: @JafarKofahi just replace `~['"]` with `~['"\r\n]`, it should report a syntax error in the first and third command

Comment: Yea that would solve this example, but strings in the script I am parsing can have new lines. This is why I started thinking of the modes hoping to scope the strings

Comment: @JafarKofahi if you want to support improperly nested quotes, you'll have an ambiguous grammar, you'll need to think about that.

Comment: Shell does support this nesting, so it is proper usage. But I agree with you that with a tool like ANTLR it doesnt seem to be easily doable. If I have programmatical control over the lexing/parsing this wouldnt have been as big of a deal as it is. But thank you for your answer and insight. If you have any further suggestion or idea please let me know

Comment: @JafarKofahi you need to *define* precisely how your language is supposed to behave, maybe you can sort it out with ANTLR (it's tweakable after all)