# Analyze a string between quotation marks containing single quotation marks with ANTLR

Tags: antlr4

I would like to be able to parse a string like "test ' test"
 with ANTLR4

My grammar :

```
QUOTE: ('\''|'"');
STRING: QUOTE .*? QUOTE;
```

My parser :

```
matcher: STRING;
```

On another post the following possibility is proposed :
[Handling scope for single and double quote strings in ANTLR4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938926/handling-scope-for-single-and-double-quote-strings-in-antlr4)

grammar :

```
SQUOTE: '\'';
DQUOTE: '"';

STRING: (SQUOTE .*? SQUOTE | DQUOTE .*? DQUOTE );
```

However, this possibility creates redundancy and consequently risks during maintenance

That's why I would like to know if there was a possibility of finding an equivalent of the regex:

```regex
("|').*?(\1)
```

That is to say, to automatically search for the same type of closing tag as the opening tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `("|').*?(\1)` isn't possible. I'd also not do `.*?`, but something like this:

```
STRING
 : '"' ~["]* '"'
 | '\'' ~[']* '\''
 ;
```

Or, if you allow escaped characters:

```
STRING
 : '"' ( ~["]* | '\\' . )* '"'
 | '\'' ( ~[']* | '\\' . ) '\''
 ;
```

Also note that `~["]*` also matches line breaks. If you don't want that, do this: `~["\r\n]*`

Comment: Okay, thank you for your responsiveness and for your answer.